# Intuition for the Discrete$\dashv$Forgetful$\dashv$Indiscrete Adjunction in $\mathsf{Top}$

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Section 9 of CWM's chapter on limits beings by introducing the adjunctions $D\dashv U \dashv I$ where $D$ is the forgetful functor, $D$ equips sets with the discrete topology, and $I$ equips sets with the indiscrete topology

I'm trying to obtain intuition for why $D$ is left adjoint and $I$ is right adjoint, but I'm having a lot of trouble. Thinking in terms of reflections, my inuition for a left adjoint here is "the orthogonal projection of a particular set on $\mathsf{Top}$". I don't see why this should be the set with the discrete topology and not the indiscrete one. I don't have any co-intuition for co-reflections..

***Added:*** I understand the adjunctions, which are just statements of the fact that any function from a discrete topological space is continuous and any function to an indiscrete topological space is continuous. The question is really about *left and right adjoints*, in particular, intuition for their "handedness".

Answer (score 1):

You've got your (co)reflections backwards. These two adjunctions give us two subcategories of $\mathsf{Top}$, the discrete and indiscrete spaces, which are coreflective and reflective respectively, and which are both equivalent to $\mathsf{Set}$.

Note also that <strike>the connected components functor provides an additional adjoint $\pi_0 \dashv D$,</strike> analogous "discrete $\dashv$ underlying $\dashv$ indiscrete" adjunctions between some category and $\mathsf{Set}$ show up in other places, cf. [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46877/natural-examples-of-sequences-of-adjoint-functors/46879#46879) by Steve Lack, and that often "connected components" provides a 4th adjoint in the string, $\pi_0 \dashv D$, but that $\pi_0 \not \dashv D$ in the case of $\mathsf{Top}$, although we do have $\pi_0 \dashv D$ if we replace $\mathsf{Top}$ by the subcategory of locally connected spaces.

Comment: I only know that we have an extra adjoint under the hypothesis of local-connectedness.

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right -- $\pi_0$ is not left adjoint to $D$ unless by "$\mathsf{Top}$" we actually mean "locally connected spaces". [I even realized this at some point](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/04/on_a_topological_topos.html#c046308). The discussion I linked to in my answer gets around this by the somewhat insidious step of redefining "$\mathsf{Top}$".

Comment: @tcamps I don't understand, shouldn't left adjoints be thought of as reflections and right adjoints as coreflections? Could you provide more intuitive insight on why $D$ should be left adjoint and $I$ right adjoint? I don't feel at all ready to tackle the 'string of adjunctions' you mentioned.

Comment: That is what's happening, the reflection onto discrete spaces is a left adjoint and vice versa. There's no need for intuition on this-just check that maps (in Top) out of the discrete space on a set are maps (in Set) out of the set and that maps into the indiscrete space are maps into the set.

Comment: I agree with Kevin Carlson: just check that a map $DS \to X$ is the same as a function $DS \to UX$. It's very simple. As to the question "Shouldn't left adjoints be thought of as reflections and right adjoints be thought of as coreflections?" the answer is decidedly: No. For example, if, as in this case, $F$ is a reflection, then its right adjoint $G$ is almost certainly not a coreflection.

Comment: There's some ambiguity in what "reflective" and "coreflective" mean. Sometimes a "reflective subcategory" is required to be a full subcategory, sometimes not. I prefer to require that a reflective subcategory is full, because there's really not a lot that's useful to say about non-full reflective subcategories. There are lots of adjunctions that are not equivalent to the inclusions of full reflective or coreflective subcategories: for example the usual adjunction between $\mathsf{Set}$ and $\mathsf{Ab}$ or any other algebraic category.

Comment: @tcamps I think I am confused about the definition of adjoints via relfections then, although I did not mean 'reflection' as in the context of reflective subcategories, but rather in the sense of the following definition:
Borceux: "A functor $R:\mathsf B \rightarrow \mathsf A$ is left adjoint to the functor $F:\mathsf A \rightarrow \mathsf B$ when there exists a natuarl transformation $\eta :1_{\mathsf B} \Rightarrow FR$ such that for every $B\in \mathsf B$, $(RB, \eta _B)$ is a reflection of $B$ along $F$."
This seems to say the a left adjoint is the "orthogonal projection" (informally)

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. You should probably clarify what "orthogonal projection" means informally to you, and then figure out which aspects of that meaning do hold and which ones fail in this context.

Comment: Where are you getting "This seems to says that the left adjoint is the orthogonal projection (informally)" from?

Comment: @tcamps sorry for the long delay, I didn't notice you replied here. By orthogonal projection I informally mean that you assign to an object in a category the "closest" object to it in another, more structured category. The example I have in mind is free constructions, which send less structured objects to their "closest" counterparts. The quote you mentioned comes from reading that usually left adjoints *add* structure and right adjoints forget it.